# Clicking a link using selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, dom-events

Here is the link I'm trying to click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="OpenAddKeywords();return false;" id="btnAddKeywords">Add Keywords</a>
```

I tried a few options(listed below) but they didn't work; any ideas?

1. `self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnAddKeywords']").click()`
2. `self.br.execute_script("OpenAddKeywords();return false;")`

This is the error I've got for `execute_script`:

> Message: u'Error Message => \'Can\'t find variable: OpenAddKeywords\'\n caused by Request =>

And this is the one that I've got for `xpath`:

> Message: u'Error Message => \'Unable to find element with xpath \'//*[@id=\'btnAddKeywords\']\'\'\n caused by Request =>

Comment: How exactly they didn't work?

Comment: Did you try `self.br.find_element_by_id('btnAddKeywords').click()`? If that's not working, it's that you may not be on the page you think you are.

Comment: I have the same problem, you can also track [my thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769532/unable-to-perform-click-action-in-selenium-python) to find a solution.

Comment: I have solved the problem; see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769532/unable-to-perform-click-action-in-selenium-python?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Zeinab You solution worked for me. You should post it as an answer here.

Comment: @rozkosz, I'm really happy about that. I've posted it.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769532/unable-to-perform-click-action-in-selenium-python/19786501#19786501), the problem would be solved by means of `ActionChains` class; a brief code is here:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("someid")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()
```

The main problem is that in some cases, specially when you have a some javascript codes in your page, the DOM would change and the element you've found before will be staled. 'ActionChains' would keep it alive to perform actions on.

Comment: @Mark My problem was very similar to yours and Zeinab's solution worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use xpath like below. It is working for me because i have used last project.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click()
```

Please try it...

Comment: Actually @Mark tried this and mentioned the result in the question; please read the question carefully and then answer. :)